# How to get number of followers on twitter using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to output the number of followers one user has on twitter using tweepy, I have searched high and low to find some answers and I managed to get some code:

```
import oauth, tweepy, sys, locale, threading 
from time import localtime, strftime, sleep

def init(): 
    global api
    consumer_key = "..."
    consumer_secret = "..."
    access_key = "..."
    access_secret = "..."
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    user = tweepy.api.get_user('...')
    print user.screen_name
    print user.followers_count
```

when I run this in python, i get errors of bad authentication,

could someone please explain why this is?

Thanks

Comment: Are your credentials correct?

Comment: do you mean the consumer and access stuff? if so then yes because I managed to stream twitter using a different script I have written.

Comment: You should double-check your credentials. This is more of a Twitter error than a Tweepy error, as Twitter isn't accepting your provided credentials

Answer (score 3):

You create the `api` object with the authentication, but then you don't use it and call tweepy directly.

This line:

```
user = tweepy.api.get_user('...')
```

Should be:

```
user = api.get_user('...')
```

Comment: I want to get the followers list for a specific Twitter user, can you please guide me, here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76726633/get-twitter-account-followers-using-api-and-google-apps-script